# Entity Framework References go missing between debug and release build

Tags: c#, entity-framework-6, console-application

There must be something that I don't understand in the difference between debug builds and release builds and its use of references. I'm using Entity Framework 6 to connect to a database that has previously been set up. I am able to successfully build and run the project while it is in Debug mode. If I change it to release mode I instantly get build errors indicating that the namespaces and types that were just there can no longer be found. I checked and as far as I can tell they both target framework .Net 4.5 which I saw may have been an issue for some other people. I see no difference in what is listed under references in my solution explorer.

I'm using visual studio 2013. Happy to provide any code but I don't know what would be most relevant.

Some of the errors that I'm getting:

```
The type or namespace name 'Entity' does not exist in the namespace    System.Data' (are you missing an assembly reference?) in Holds.Context.cs
The type or namespace name 'DbContext' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?) in Holds.Context.cs
The type or namespace name 'DbSet' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?) in Holds.Context.cs
```

Thanks for any guidance that can be provided.

Comment: Your config file, see if you can expand it and there will be 2 configs for release vs debug.  Check those.

Comment: I have the same problem.  Let me know if you find a solution.

Comment: Ditto. solution will build in Debug mode but not in Release mode. Entity framework was installed into the solution via Nuget Package Manager

Comment: Please see [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/33751526/254215) for how I resolved it following @OomPiet's advice.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Switching to release mode then re-installing entity framework on the problem project fixed this issue in my case.

Comment: Although this may solve OP's issue it would be best to elaborate on your answer with detailed steps on how to do it.

Comment: This resolved my issue and my steps are detailed in my answer [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/33751526/254215).

Answer (score 10):

To resolve this I used @**OomPiet**'s answer. For me the steps were as follows:

1. Switch to Debug Mode
2. Rebuild solution - Build Successful
3. Switch to Release Mode
4. Rebuild solution - Build Failed
5. In `Solution Explorer` click on the project that will not build (mine was a unit test project)
6. Right Click project > `Manage NuGet Packages`
7. Ensure `Installed packages`is selected
8. Select `EntityFramework`
9. Click `Uninstall` and close dialog
10. Click on Solution in `Solution Explorer`
11. Right Click > `Manage NuGet Packages for Solution`
12. Ensure `Installed packages`is selected
13. Select `EntityFramework`
14. Click `Manage`
15. Ensure the project which is causing issue is `checked`
16. Click `OK` and close dialog after installing
17. Click Click on Solution in `Solution Explorer`
18. Right Click 'Rebuild Solution'

Now I can switch between `Debug` and `Release` without compilation failing. I hope that helps

**EDIT:**
If you have only one project using EF, see **@LuckyLikey**'s comment below where he states *to search for EF instead, and install it in that project*.

Comment: Man you saved my day.. I couldn't believe my eyes when i had this issue. *pukes in trash* - However just to complete your already perfect answer: If the Project which causes those problem is the only project using EF, the Framework will no more be visible to `Manage` in Step 14. *Just search for EF instead and `install` it in your Project on Release Mode.* This will also fix the issue.

Comment: Fair comment. I will edit my answer and quote and refer to your comment. Thanks for the additional information.

Answer (score 7):

Ok @Dim and @Oompiet's answers are correct but there's a really easy way to do this via the Package Manager Console:

```
Update-Package -reinstall EntityFramework
```

That will do it at the Solution level or if you want to do it at the project level just do:

```
Update-Package -reinstall EntityFramework -p <YouProjectName>
```

Answer (score 0):

In Debug mode, there is extra information with the assemblies (the pdb file).

This allows the application to fetch the extra dependencies.

In release mode, there is no such things, thus the assemblies must be referenced.

Doing step 10 to 18 from @Dib will solve the issue.