# VisualStudio 2017, Debug build is ok, but Release not work at all

Tags: wpf, visual-studio, nuget

[image: Debug OK, Release lost "all using..."]

- Visual Studio 2017
- Windows 10 Build 10586.753
- UwpDesktop 10.0.14393.3 installed by NuGet
- WPF application

When build as "debug", In debug, All "using" work fine then Compile success.

but Build as "Release", Some Using is not enable. then,
Almost method make compile error..

Do you have Any idea ?

**Update1** : I tried this. but Not work... : (
and I make new project and install UwpDesktop as "release" mode. but Result is same. Oh my god !
[Entity Framework References go missing between debug and release build](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30596832/entity-framework-references-go-missing-between-debug-and-release-build)

**Update2** : I check "Release" folder, It was empty.

"Debug" folder has lot of DLL of UwpDesktop.
then, I copy all file except Exe from Debug to Release.
Now, I success to do compile at Release.

**but Why ?**
Is this normal ?

**Update 3**
Now , To build as "Release" is possible, but next issue is Installer. "Visual Studio Installer" has same error when release compile... : (

**Update 4**
Error message is , 
It's normal message when We put wrong or Unknown class name in code. In case of above picture, GattDeviceService is unknown class name.

Now, Situation change to good.

( 1 ) I copy all DLL file from Debug folder to Release folder. All DLL file was placed by NuGet first. I wonder Why NuGut did not copy same DLL to Release folder.

( 2 ) and Now, "Visual Studio Installer" also worked fine. I tried many. then, I do not remember what I did.  First error was missing dependencies like first issue. After I copy DLL file to "Release", Installer build did not success.

(2-1)  Here is current status. ( see image )

[image]

(2-2)  If I selected "Project output" with "Visual Studio Installer", Build failed, then, I changed "file" instead of "Project output" and I selected all EXE , DLL, PDB, Config files. if I select xml, winmd, Installer setup show error message. then, I ignore it.

Now, I resolve this issue ( Build with release is success, Setup build with release : success )

I hope it help someone.. : )

Comment: Which kind of error messages did you get during you compile your app in release mode? If no any files in release folder, please make sure that you set the correct output path in your project property like "bin\Release". Please also not optimize code and set the debugging information=full under the Advanced Build Settings window. For the Installer, do you create the setup project using click-once or others?

Comment: Hi, Jack. Thank you. I added "Update 4". Now I resolve this all issue. but It's not very easy for beginner.  Thank you for your comment.

Comment: Glad to know that you have resolved this issue, if possible, would you please add your solution as a singly reply answer(not in your previous issue or comment) and mark it as the answer? So it could help other community members who meet the same issue to find the answer easily. Have a nice day:)

Comment: Here is simple step to resolve this issue.  ( 1 ) Copy all DLL file from "Debug" folder to "Release".    (  2  )  if "this.InitializeComponent();" has error, Remove Project with Solution Exploler and Re-add it.   (   3  ) and For "Visual Studio Installer" , Do not use "Project output" to select target file. Use  "file" to select files and do not select "winmd" files.     DONE !

Comment: really thanks for your sharing :), but if possible, you could share it as the answer with the "Post Your answer" option(not post it as the comment), so you could mark it and help other members. Sincerely:)

Answer (score -2):

Here is simple step to resolve this issue.

1. Copy all DLL file from "Debug" folder to "Release".
2. If "this.InitializeComponent();" has error, Remove Project with Solution Exploler and Re-add it.
3. And For "Visual Studio Installer", Do not use "Project output" to select target file. Use "file" to select files and do not select "winmd" files.

Comment: "Copy all DLL file from "Debug" folder to "Release". sounds and feel so  wrong